# Should I escape shell arguments in Perl?

Tags: perl, shell, arguments

When using [system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) calls in Perl, do you have to escape the shell args, or is that done automatically?

The arguments will be user input, so I want to make sure this isn't exploitable.

Comment: What do you mean, escape shell args? Do you mean putting \'s before any characters like ">" or " " or do you want to include escaping $'s so people can't inject your Perl variables? Or what? Give an example of what you mean.

Comment: How to add curly braces inside System calls....           system("$jboss_client /subsystem=logging/size-rotating-file-handler=SAMPLE:add\\(formatter=\{yyyy\} \\)"); I am always getting the out like below.... formatter=yyyy instaed of farmatter={yyyy}. Can you give me an IDEA to resolve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you use `system $cmd, @args` rather than `system "$cmd @args"` (an array rather than a string), then you do not have to escape the arguments because no shell is invoked (see [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)).  `system {$cmd} $cmd, @args` will not invoke a shell either even if $cmd contains metacharacters and @args is empty (this is documented as part of [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)).  If the args are coming from user input (or other untrusted source), you will still want to untaint them. See `-T` in the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) docs, and the [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) docs.

If you need to read the output or send input to the command, `qx` and `readpipe` have no equivalent.  Instead, use `open my $output, "-|", $cmd, @args` or `open my $input, "|-", $cmd, @args` although this is not portable as it requires a real `fork` which means Unix only... I think.  Maybe it'll work on Windows with its simulated fork.  A better option is something like [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Run/), which will also handle the case of piping commands to other commands, which neither the multi-arg form of system nor the 4 arg form of open will handle.

Comment: As an addition, `system {'cmd'} 'cmd'` always bypasses `sh` even if `'cmd'` contains characters that would normally be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: You should add that the *reason* why you don't have to escape shell metacharacters with "system 'cmd' @args" is that no shell is being invoked in this case (since the OP asked wether shell metachars would be escaped "automatically" which is not the case).

Comment: +1, I'm with chaos -- I never heard of the indirect-object syntax before!

Comment: The "-|" and "|-" piped open() modes work fine on Windows when used in the 3-or-more-arguments form -- no simulated fork() is required (for that, anyway).  What doesn't work is using them in the 2-arg form to try to communicate with a forked child process.

Comment: I've been testing the "system" and "open my $output" solutions, but neither let me redirect STDERR to a file, which sadly means I can't use the solution in my scenario. I assume that is working as designed, but wanted to share in case that info helps others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413344/calling-system-commands-from-perl

Comment: @Dan: See docs for open(). You can dup then redirect STDERR, run your command, then restore STDERR.

Comment: @schulwitz - he wants to redirect stderr to a file, try it, it works.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, the situation is a bit nastier.  Basically, all Win32 programs receive one long command-line string -- the shell (usually `cmd.exe`) may do some interpretation first, removing `<` and `>` redirections for example, but it does *not* split it up at word boundaries for the program.  Each program must do this parsing themselves (if they wish -- some programs don't bother).  In C and C++ programs, routines provided by the runtime libraries supplied with the compiler toolchain will generally perform this parsing step before `main()` is called.

The problem is, in general, *you don't know how a given program will parse its command line*.  Many programs are compiled with some version of MSVC++, whose [quirky parsing rules are described here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx), but many others are compiled with different compilers that use different conventions.

This is compounded by the fact that `cmd.exe` has its own quirky parsing rules.  The caret (`^`) is treated as an escape character that quotes the following character, and text inside double quotes is treated as quoted if a list of tricky criteria are met (see `cmd /?` for the full gory details).  If your command contains any strange characters, it's very easy for `cmd.exe`'s idea of which parts of text are "quoted" and which aren't to get out of sync with your target program's, and all hell breaks loose.

So, the safest approach for escaping arguments on Windows is:

1. Escape arguments in the manner expected by the command-line parsing logic of the program you're calling.  (Hopefully you know what that logic is; if not, try a few examples and guess.)
2. Join the escaped arguments with spaces.
3. Prefix *every single non-alphanumeric character* of the resulting string with `^`.
4. Append any redirections or other shell trickery (e.g. joining commands with `&&`).
5. Run the command with `system()` or backticks.

Comment: Interesting information - thank you.  It doesn't endear Windows to this Unixophile, but it helps to know what happens behind the scenes.  (The ref'd page is a bit quiet about the role of caret!  It mentions it, but only by exception.  It is not clear how it handles ^\ or ^", for example.)

Comment: I agree with Jonathan Leffler. That is (in my opinion) an awful way to handle command-line arguments.

Comment: I totally agree that it's a terrible situation.  Though in fairness, most of the terribleness probably arises from MS's laudable devotion to maintaining backwards compatibility.  (To see just how obsessive they are, check out Raymond Chen's excellent blog sometime.)

Comment: @Jonathan: To clarify, two levels of encoding are necessary -- the caret is seen *only* by cmd.exe, which removes it when it passes the command line to the program being run. The rules on that page describe how a MSVC++-compiled program will parse its cmd line (i.e. the 2nd layer of parsing).

Comment: +1, and thanks for the link from my blog to this answer :)  I agree that it is terrible, and you have given good resources on tackling the problem.  I wonder if there is a tool to auto-escape this stuff that is already aware of the correct escaping logic.  That would make things like this less trial-and-error.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: No problem :)  I'm afraid I haven't looked for a tool.  If it did exist it would be flaky though, because it would need to guess which runtime library the called program was compiled with (MSVC is probably right 95% of the time)...

Answer (score 2):

```
 sub esc_chars {
  # will change, for example, a!!a to a\!\!a
     @_ =~ s/([;<>\*\|`&\$!#\(\)\[\]\{\}:'"])/\\$1/g;
     return @_;
  }
```

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/slac/www/resource/how-to-use/cgi-rexx/cgi-esc.html

Comment: Does anyone know where this list of characters come from? I could not find it perl docs. I'd rather not read the source code of Perl's exec function it that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use system "$cmd @args" (a string), then you have to escape the arguments because a shell is invoked.

Fortunately, for double quoted strings, only four characters need escaping:

```
"    - double quote
$    - dollar
@    - at symbol
\    - backslash
```

Comment: I think OP was talking about shell interpretation, not avoiding accidental interpolation of scalars and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The answers on your question were very useful.  In the end I followed @runrig's advice but then used the core module open3() command so I could capture the output from STDERR as well as STDOUT.

For sample code of open3() in use with @runrig's solution, see my related question and answer:
[Calling system commands from Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413344/calling-system-commands-from-perl/4424781#4424781)