# Perl Search and Replace Command Not Working When Called from Inside another Perl Script

Tags: perl, search, replace, symbols, bareword

I am a beginner with Perl. I am using the Below Perl Command To Search and Replace "/$" Sequence in my tcl Script. This works well When used on the linux Command Line directly.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl
```

I am calling to Call the above Perl One liner in another Perl script using System Command and only with " ` " Back Tick.

```
system(`perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl`);
`perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl`;
```

I am getting the Below error. Please Help With this issue.

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$/g"
(Missing operator before g?)
Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s//$/"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I Dont Know if I Can use any other Separation Operator like % and # just like SED command but, When I used '%' operator for separation, I didn't see error but job is not done.

```
`perl -p -i -e 's%\/\$%\/\\\$%g' sed_list.tcl`;
```

I couldn't find sufficient results for this particular issue of '$' variable on the web. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619926/should-i-escape-shell-arguments-in-perl

Comment: Why are using backtick with system command? You should use `" "` like `system(" ")` .

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
    system("perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl");
This I have already tried but of no use,. I still get the same error. Please suggest a fix. I will try and update you

Comment: If you have tried something and doesn't work, try to fix it but for that do not use wrong syntax.

Comment: Make it more readable, please use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) and any other delimiter than `/` like this `s{\Q/$}{\Q\$}g`

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out .. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an external command by passing the command to a system function or by using **backticks(``)** operator. Please pass the command to the **system()** function as a string:

`system(q{perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl})`

or use backticks as:

```
`perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list_gen.tcl`
```

Edit:
As suggested by Paul in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I am using System Function like you have specified, I am getting the below error
"syntax error at flat_rtl_gen.pl line 175, near "system"
Execution of flat_rtl_gen.pl aborted due to compilation errors."

When I used Back Ticks, I am getting The below Error
"Backticks found where operator expected at flat_rtl_gen.pl line 177, near "`"perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list_gen.tcl"`"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at flat_rtl_gen.pl line 177, near "`"perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list_gen.tcl"`"
Please Suggest . .

Comment: I tried out and didn't find any errors. Can you please post flat_rtl_gen.pl? Also do "perl -c flat_rtl_gen.pl" and post the result. Please edit the question to add these details.

Comment: Hi silent Monk, the below code worked 
`perl -p -i -e 's/\\\/\\\$/\\\/\\\\\\\$\g' file`;     I am really thank ful to you for your time. I will try out your code and will update you ..

Comment: I can not post flat_rtl_gen script as it is proprietary script. 
When I did "perl -c flat_rtl_gen.pl $PWD". I got a msg saying that Syntax OK. But when I am running with the fix that you have given, I am still getting an error saying that "Syntax error at -e, near "s//$/" "

Comment: Thanks once again for your time :D

Comment: The problem with the first statement here is that your system command is using double quotes, which causes each backslash to be treated as an escape character *before* the string is passed to the argument of `perl -p -i -e`.  As a result you'd have to double-backslash all of the meta characters.  You can get around it by just using non-interpolating quotes:

`system(q{perl -p -i -e 's/\/\$/\/\\\$/g' sed_list.tcl});`

Answer (score 0):

Some one here Suggested that I should Escape all Back Slashes while using System Command or calling another command using BackTicks from inside a perl script. But later they have deleted their answer. It worked for me. I would like to thank every one for taking effort and helping me out in solving my question.

Here is the correct working code.

```
`perl -p -i -e 's/\\\/\\\$/\\\/\\\\\\\$/g' sed_list_gen.tcl`;
```

or Use System function as shown Below

```
system("perl -p -i -e 's/\\\/\\\$/\\\/\\\\\\\$/g' sed_list_gen.tcl");
```

Thanks once again for the community for helping me out. . .

Comment: My goodness that's disastrously messy.  You can take two steps to clean it up.  1) Use non-interpolating quotes for your `system()` command.  2) Use a delimiter other than `/` for your search-and-replace:  `system(q{perl -p -i -e's!/\$!/\\$!'});`